How to get data from google play console
I'm creating an app as a school project. Our publisher on Google Play is a friend who has access to the Google Play Console. We need from him statistics on how many people have interacted with our app, so we can send it to our teacher. Unfortunately, he doesn't accept a format where we add the number of active users plus those who uninstalled. The number of beneficiaries has to be a clear figure without any guesses. Unfortunately, my friend doesn't know how to find such statistics, and I don't have access to the Google Console. He only found us data on active users. The data I'm looking for is the number of people who have had or currently have my app since its release. Please provide some instructions that I can send to the publisher to find the appropriate statistics.
Thanks!
